# Voltage doubler circuit working

Tags: diodes, voltage-doubler

[image: voltage doubler circuit]

[image: output voltage plot]

I understand that when the voltage at the anode of the first diode is greater than the cathode it turns on, however immediately after the first two positive cycles, how does the diode turn on?
It would be very helpful if someone could give me an insight into what is actually happening.
I have been stuck on it for hours.

Comment: Doubler without load charges C2 to 2Vin-2Vd after few periods and then both diodes stops to conduct. The reason is C1 stays charged to Vin-Vd so D1 cannot conduct and charged C1 anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple example of what's called a charge pump. It works by alternatingly charging up one capacitor, then "pumping" that capacitor's charge into another capacitor by putting it in series with the same source that charged it in the first place.

Here's a step by step (let's use Vpk to mean the peak voltage of the source, and Vf the forward voltage of the diodes, which we'll assume are identical):

1. On the negative half-cycle of the AC source, capacitor C1 is put across the source by D1 and is charged up to Vpk-Vf. No current goes through C2 at this point as it's blocked by D2.
2. Then on the positive half-cycle, D1 turns off and D2 turns on, putting C1 in series with the source, so C2 now sees a voltage source that peaks at Vpk+Vc1, or 2Vpk-Vf. This charges C2 up to 2Vpk-2Vf (a second diode drop because of D2).

This isn't perfect, because I've neglected the fact that C1 discharges in the process of charging C2, meaning it can't charge all the way after just one cycle. In actuality, the first cycle only gets C2 to about 1.5Vpk-2Vf (assuming C1 and C2 have the same capacitance), and it takes several cycles to get C2 all the way to 2Vpk-2Vf. (Actually, it's exponential decay, so C2 is never fully charged, but it gets arbitrarily close very quickly.)

Answer (score 1):

> *It would be very helpful if someone could give me an insight into what
> is actually happening.*

It's no different to a transformer and bridge rectifier feeding a smoothing capacitor; once the capacitor is fully charged then the diodes will never become forward biased enough to pass current to the capacitor.

Of course, if the capacitor voltage droops (due to an external load current) then, the diodes will conduct every cycle to top-up the capacitor voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The plot of the cathode voltage of D1/the *diode to ground* (*first* diode?) as well as the anode voltage of D2/the *series diode* is green, not deep blue.
It dips below *diodebottom* (purple) for a shrinking fraction of each input  cycle, center to the left of/before the negative input peak.

Comment: Now, about the "twin peaks" current waveforms… I don't know. I'd try a load resistance in parallel to C2 - starting with 3k3.